# Return back to iPhone app from safari

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

From my iphone app I an calling a url in safari.How can i revert back to my iphone app from that webpage

just like we return back to our apps after facebook authentication ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I tryed to call a url on safari from my app.I found some tutorials call back methods but really not getting the idea

Any way if u give any kind-even one line of answer and upvote me,i would have agreed
But anyone can do this thing without having any knowledge..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a URL scheme if you have control of the web page.  Simply add a link using your scheme.

If your scheme is `myapp:` then:

`<a href="myapp://return_info">Return to the app</a>`

See [this site](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/) for a tutorial.

Comment: I have controll of the webpage.But how can I come back to app on a button click from web page ??

Comment: Did you read the link?  **URL schemes** will allow you to relaunch the app as well as pass information (in the form of the URL) back to the app.

Comment: yep I did..But that link tells about switching two apps,right ?

Comment: Ok, here's a link that spells it out more clearly: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: thanks Richard..I allready have gone through that

but.. what should I write in this 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
  // Do something with the url here
}

Comment: Take the user back to where they were when they left the app.  If the website was doing something it needs to tell the app pass it back in as values in the querystring.  Your app has access to the url that called it in the `url` parameter.

Comment: thank you richard for your patience..